# Ember.js (RC1) CollectionView.didInsertElement fired too early

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working with an extended `Ember.CollectionView` with a large set of children. I need to perform some styling javascript handled by a jQuery plugin after all of the children have rendered. My first attempt at this was to harness the `didInsertElement` hook that I know and love, but it appears that this hook fires too early for my purposes.

According to the documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html#event_didInsertElement), this hook is fired when

> Called when the element of the view has been inserted into the DOM. Override this function to do any set up that requires an element in the document body.

So perhaps, I have a misunderstanding of how Ember renders, but it would appear from this that my approach should work.

Am I encountering a bug? Is this correct functionality that I've misunderstood? And are there canonical workarounds other than using a checkin style system with a callback to alert me when each of the child views have fired `didInsertElement`?

**Edit** For the record, using a checkin system does work. I keep count of which child views checkin when each time the parent `didInsertElement` fired, but I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically the CollectionView is inserted before it's children, so yes, this is the correct functionality. 
To add a callback to a CollectionView for when all it's children have been rendered you need to use the `afterRender` queue.

```
App.ContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
      // this will be performed after every child has been rendered
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it appears the afterRender queue is not working like we'd like it to either. I set up logging from didInsertElement on the parent view, from the afterRender queue, and from didInsertElement on the child views and this is what I see in my log: https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/5099953. It shows the `afterRender` call happening before any child views render

Comment: Are you loading the content for the Array behind the collection view asynchronously?

Comment: I feel kinda like a dunce... Yeah, yeah I am loading it asynchronously. So I accept on this one, from the scope of my original question, this is the answer. Thanks